# How To Uninstall Program In Ubuntu

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall

I opening terminal and writing

```
sudo apt-get remove Kazam
```

but it does not work:

```
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package Kazam
```

How can I uninstall Kazam?

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy kazam` ?  In the line that says "Installed: " is there a version number or does it say "(none)"?

Answer (score 3):

The correct package name is `kazam` (with a lowercase "k").

Therefore you have to run the command this way:

```
sudo apt-get remove kazam
```

Comment: apt will remove it regardless of case.

Comment: but i tried doesnt't work

Comment: Oh i solved the correct: sudo apt remove kazam thank you!

Comment: @Dorian No, both `apt` and `apt-get` are case sensitive. You're wrong.

Comment: @CoolKetchup If this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the grey round check button on its left. You also mark your question as solved this way.

Comment: @ByteCommander Works on my system regardless of case.  Try it on yours.  I can test `sudo apt remove gedit` and `.. Gedit` and it still asks if I want to uninstall it.

Comment: @Dorian No, that does not work on my system and it should not even work. Something is strange on your side. What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Gnome 14.04 LTS

Comment: @Dorian Okay, I have to apologize. Seems like `apt-get` was indeed case insensitive on 14.04. This is no longer true on 16.04 though, I don't know when they fixed this "feature-bug" though.